# Remove trailing whitespace and terminating character

Tags: regex, trim

```
String val = "this is a string        *"
```

I am attempting to remove the final character '*' along with any preceding whitespace with the following output:

```
String result = "this is a string"
```

What's the simplest and **sturdiest** approach to doing this?

Should I substring the final character and trim the string or use regex?

Comment: Match `\s*\*$` and replace by empty string.

Comment: Thanks anub, can you briefly explain the regex?

Comment: Language depending, basic string manipulation? `val.substr(0, val.length - 1).trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching you can use:

```
\s*\*$
```

Which is 0 or more whitespace characters followed by literal * character with anchor `$` to assert end of line.

That needs to be replaced by empty string `""` to remove it.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V60uK5/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly as you suggested.  I modified it to `\s*\*\s$` to allow for potential whitespace after the asterisk only at the end of the line.  Thanks very much.

Comment: For optional whitespace after `*` I suggest using `\s*\*\s*$`